# Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error

Tags: apt

getting below error. But I think available space is enough for this (use% is 9%)
Can you please help us to resolve this ?

```
lab@lab:~$ sudo -E apt-get install subversion apache2-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
subversion is already the newest version (1.9.7-4ubuntu1).
apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.4+2.02-2ubuntu8.3) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
grub-efi-amd64-signed
shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

lab@lab:~$ df -k .
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      479152840 37427836 417315612   9% /
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  It mentions EFI so I'd check to see if you have a separate /boot partition, and it has space first. Next the most common cause; do you have inodes left?  `df -hi`  (the -h isn't needed, I just hate find larger numbers harder to read).

Comment: lab@lab:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            935M     0  935M   0% /dev
tmpfs           193M  1.5M  192M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G   36G  399G   9% /
/dev/sda1       511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi

Comment: lab@lab:~$ df -hi
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             234K   471  234K    1% /dev
tmpfs            241K   804  240K    1% /run
/dev/sda2         30M  579K   29M    2% /
/dev/sda1           0     0     0     - /boot/efi

lab@lab:~$

Comment: we have a separate /boot partition, its showing /dev/sda1       511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi and we have enough space on it.

Comment: i have run teh command for checking inodes, its showing the output is 0, /dev/sda1           0     0     0     - /boot/efi

Comment: Please edit your question, and add additional info there (*it allows far better formatting than comments do, plus better edit capability - even if you forget using the {} for 'code' quotes; others can do it for you*)

Comment: changed the question

Comment: I don't see the inode info in your question?   It's unreadable in comments sorry, and it was this info I was after moved to your question.  You can reply to me or any user via comments, but additional info (such as the `df -h` suggested in my first comment) should go up in your question, along with subsequent info you've wrongly put in comments..  *If new users come and read your question looking to help, they'll see what you add in questions, but often ignore comments* :)

Comment: /dev/sda1           0     0     0     - /boot/efi

Comment: this is teh output when i am running df -i , and i have tried to cd /boot/efi , getting the message as no permission even i am logged in as root

Comment: @guiverc Although I also have a hard time reading the details in the comments, I doubt inodes are exhausted in the OP’s case. I can’t see any 100% used, the numbers are generally very low. There are zero inodes for `/dev/sda1` aka `/boot/efi` which probably means it’s a FAT partition.

Comment: See this bug report, looks like same thing. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim-signed/+bug/1776271  If so please say it effects you, the more with an issue the sooner someone will look at it.

Answer (score 11):

There have been a number of reports that if the NVRAM is more than 50% used, the efibootmgr will fail because there's a concern about being able to garbage collect EFI variables properly, or some such.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find a clear way to determine the used/free space in NVRAM, so I'm going on suspicion.

There are a number of potential solutions to this:

1. **Clear the dump files**

   grub stores efi logs in `/sys/fs/efi/efivars/dump-*`

   Try deleting these to see if that's enough to bring the used space down.  Then run `apt -f install` to see if the error has changed.
2. **BIOS upgrade**

   If your hardware provider has a BIOS/EFI upgrade, then I'd recommend doing that also, then try `apt -f install` again.
3. **LAST RESORT - DISABLE EFI CHECK**

   It's a little dangerous, because you could technically fill your NVRAM to a point were it's unbootable.  However, I have used this process successfully on a Dell R420.

   To override the check, add "efi_no_storage_paranoia" to the kernel option.  To do this:

   1. Append "efi_no_storage_paranoia" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX variables in `/etc/default/grub`
   2. Update grub by running `sudo update-grub`
   3. Reboot
   4. Run `apt -f install`

For safety, I reverse this process afterward also.  **Kernel safety override parameters are not something you want to leave lying around!**

Comment: On Debian Stretch it's not `/sys/fs/efi/` but `/sys/firmware/efi/`

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 it's `/sys/firmware/efi/` as well

Comment: The only procedure that worked for me was the number 3 of of this answer

Comment: The first one worked. `/sys` is the folder on the `/dev/sda1` and there is space about few Gb there. So why did it work? What is the reason?

Comment: +1 for #3! Works like a charm! I have an Intel DN2800MT MB that has very little NVRAM (it seems). I'll leave the "no paranoia" flag there from now on. Not a critical machine (just my backup router). I have enough paranoia going on already! :D

Comment: @4xy `/sys` is a “pseudo file system”. It's not an actual folder on the hard disk, there's a special filesystem mounted there that consists of entries that refer to properties of the system or other devices. (If you say `mount`, you'll see an entry something like `sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`.) In this case it lets you access content in the NVRAM of your system's UEFI chip, which is not on any hard drive.

Comment: `/sys/firmware/efi` on Manjaro as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by disabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in my UEFI setup. After rebooting, the package update for 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' went through without issue.

Comment: This does not help for me (Thinkpad T440s). Will this delete any variables or make some room otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

OK I just encountered the same error and have successfully solved thanks for the helpful answer by [@tu-Reinstate Monica-dor duh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072618/could-not-prepare-boot-variable-no-space-left-on-device-grub-install-error-ef/1211283#1073318). His/her answer explained the exact reason of the error.

However, my way of solving this problem is by editing the built-in boot manager, which is also stored in NVRAM. In my case, I followed the steps of https://superuser.com/a/931016/672706:

1. `sudo efibootmgr -v` list all boot options.
2. `sudo efibootmgr -b # -B` to delete the unwanted options.

After ran these two steps, I have successfully installed `grub-efi-amd64-signed`.

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS, selecting `Load Defaults` did it for me.