# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Installation Freezes on "Installing grub to target devices -"

Tags: boot, grub2

The installation doesn't fail it just freezes. I've tried reflashing the iso many times and no solutions I've found on google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation fails on grub installation (UEFI mode, Thinkpad X120e)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322437/ubuntu-server-20-04-installation-fails-on-grub-installation-uefi-mode-thinkpad)